# How can I implement the observer design pattern streaming data in C++?

Tags: c++, tcp, streaming, udp, server-push

I would like to send data from a server to a client, continuously (streaming), without the need for the client to continuously loop through and check for any data. I think I am right in believing this is the observer design pattern? How is this possible?

Could someone provide me with a list of things I can google? How is the observer pattern aspect implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals2.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observer design pattern is slightly different from what you're describing:

[image]

Note that each observer gets notified by the "observable" object; so if you have a server that's continuously streaming data, then would you expect the server to "notify" you and what would you expect the server to notify you of? Every packet it sends you? Every chunk of packets?

In short: no, you can't implement the observer pattern on a client/server application. There is no (easy) way for a server to invoke a notify method on your client app and if your client gets disconnected, then it won't unregister from the observable.

So back to your question... you're limited by the architecture: blocking sockets (tcp/udp) all work by blocking until you receive data. Once you receive data, you have to loop through and call receive again in order to continuously get more data. An alternative is to use asynchronous sockets:

- http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/async_sockets.html
- [Boost Asynchronous UDP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6.html) (note, I've never used it, but it seems like it's what you might want)
- Or just [Google Asynchronous UDP sockets](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%2b%2b%20asynchronous%20UDP%20sockets).

Asynchronous socket communication is probably as close you will get to the observer pattern. Furthermore, you want to use the UDP protocol because you have streaming data and UDP is specifically designed for streaming data. If you don't want to miss any packets (due to the unreliability of UDP), then you can use [reliable UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol).

Comment: Hi. Ok maybe I shouldnt have mentioned observer pattern. I would like the client to receive data as soon as the server sends the data, without having to poll the server every so many seconds?

Comment: @Paul, async sockets will work fine and blocking sockets shouldn't require you to poll on a time period (i.e. the socket blocks until there is data to read). I'd say that 99% of time that you're polling a certain period of time indicates that "you're doing it wrong!" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement observer pattern for Client/Server use case since the communication protocol is entirely different. (RPC may be suitable, but you are using TCP so)

Anyways, what you can do is have a dedicated TCP client for receiving data. It is this TCP client and your internal class can together implement Observer pattern. With this your class will no longer have to wait (poll) on data.

Shash

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, main concern here is client application should not be blocked waiting for data from server. For that you can create one thread which will act on socket events. You can register context of you class with this thread module and whenever data is received this thread module can make a callback (notify) using the context registered.